# Reportviewer Paging

Tags: reporting-services, linq-to-entities, reportviewer

I use ReportViewer in Local processing mode and obtain data with linq-to-entites (IQueryable<>). The data also contains images, which are rendering in the report inside a table. The resulting dataset has about 30000 items when run on a sample database.

Even though the report is divided into pages, the ReportViewer still loads all records simultaneously. I changed image source from [Database] to [external], and implemented image loading through a service (.ashx) to  speed up the SQL query. Still the report viewer loads all images (not only those for the displayed page) and only than rendering report.

Do you have any idea how I can increase performance for my report? Why doesn't the report viewer use paging, but loads all data instead? Maybe I'm doing something wrong? How can I make reportviewer to load data page by page.

Answer (score 0):

From the MSDN page on **When to Use Local Processing**

"Because all data and report processing is performed on the client, you might encounter performance degradation if you attempt to process large or complex reports and queries."

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251704(v=vs.80).aspx

**Possible Solution**: Try adding a Report Filter to break up the result set in a logical manner.